# How to send image file with retrofit correctly

Tags: android, request, retrofit

I try to send a photo with the help of CatsAPI.

This is the for the upload method [upload api](https://docs.thecatapi.com/api-reference/images/images-upload).
I have an interface :

```
@Headers(value = ["content-type:multipart/form-data;"])
@POST("images/upload")
suspend fun uploadImage(
    @Header("x-api-key") apiKey: String,
    @Body body: MultipartBody,
): UploadCatResponse
```

I have this model for the request [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlSac.png).

And I have a little piece of code to call this interface

```
class SendPhotoModel {

fun uploadPhoto(
    file: File,
    listener: (Int) -> Unit
) = flow {

    val requestBody = RequestBody.create("image/*".toMediaType(), file)
    val multiPartBody = MultipartBody
        .Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addPart(requestBody)
        .build()

    val result = Api.getApi().uploadImage(
        App.ApiKeyProvider.getKey(),
        multiPartBody
    )

    emit(result)
}
```

When I the click button for sending the image to the server, it gets me message that a file not sent.
{"message":"No file sent.","status":400,"level":"info"}
What is wrong? So I try send the same file with the help of postman and it always works. But I don't know how to make the same request work in retrofit. Could you help me with this problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the entire message of the error

Comment: First, use a concrete MIME type. It is your file; you know what is in it. Beyond that... where is `file` coming from? What is the value of `file` that you are trying?

Comment: I coming file from camera, it is jpeg file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was my mistake. I was incorrectly created MultipartBody.Part object